# IBM mq- The security authentication was not valid that was supplied to queue manager 'X'. MQCC_Failed with compcode 2

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am having authentication issues when a pod is trying to connect to the IBM mq. The error that I am getting at the pod level is:

So we have a config.yaml file where it specifies which channel to and what user to use to connect from a particular env. We have dev, prod env. The prod env is working correctly however the dev env is giving the above error. However, we also have a docker file of the ibm-mq where user y is created in the base image. This is separate from the config.json file. So it is taking the user in the dockerfile rather than the user in the config.yaml file. So I want to use staging user which is mentioned in config.yml file and has all the permissions but it is using the user in the docker base image.

config.yml

```
ibm:
  mq:
    connName: x.x.x.x(1414)
    queueManager: x
    channel: x.x
    user: staging
```

Docker file

```
User y created in base image
USER 7676
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["./app.jar"]
```

The deatials of connauth and qmgr auth info are as below:

```
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(x)                      
   CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
DIS AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
     2 : DIS AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.
   AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
   AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)                        ADOPTCTX(NO)
   DESCR( )                                CHCKCLNT(REQDADM)
   CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)                      FAILDLAY(1)
   ALTDATE(2015-09-22)                     ALTTIME(19.45.35)
```

```
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').","context":"default","module":"app"}
{"timestamp":"2021-12-01 17:05:14.370","level":"ERROR","thread":"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1","logger":"org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer","message":"Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'K' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=202648, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'x' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '....'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').","context":"default","module":"app"}
```

The error that I am seeing at the queue manager is:

```
AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'y'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'y' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2282 -------------------------------------------------------
12/01/2021 04:40:45 PM - Process(1388.82388) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(....)Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.2) QMgr(Y)
```

Comment: Does  Y exist on the MQ server?  If it does not exist this error is expected. What version of MQ is on your server?

Comment: Are there any related messages immediately prior to the `AMQ9557` in the `AMQERR01.LOG`? Sometimes that error comes as a result of prior errors. If not, see @JoshMc's comment.

Comment: @morag there are a lot of warning's about it not able to reach a particular secret. Maybe that might be a reason, but for the above error some more info is that amqrmppa is the process causing it. Installation1 is what is causing it.

Comment: @JoshMc yes, I do believe that y exists on the mq server. But to be doubly sure can you please let me know how to check if y exists on the server?

Comment: If it is a Unix or Linux server just run `id y`.  I think it without be helpful if you edit you question and provide all of the related queue manager errors in full.   Giving us only amqrmppa and Installation1 is but enough to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I did a 'id y' on the mq server, it says the user does not exist. If I do a 'id mqm' it gives me the details. I have pasted the log that was present for the qmanager 'x'. @JoshMc

Comment: So we just figured that it is using the unix userid instead of the userid mention in config field while trying to connect. Any Idea why that might be happening?@JoshMc @MoragHughson

Comment: Are you sending username and password?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add details of how you connect?

Comment: You say it is using the unix userid instead of the userid mentioned in the config field. Your question has no mention of either of these things. What is the unix userid? What config are you talking about - please supply details of both by editing your question. Also, FYI, the dotted line in the AMQERR01.LOG is a separator, so anything after the dotted line is the next error message, and will be unrelated to the previous one. If you want to show us header details for the message look before it, not after it in the file.

Comment: @JoshMc  I have added the details of the how it is trying to connect.

Comment: there is nothing above this. It is the same error that I have pasted above that is being repeated. @MoragHughson

Comment: Do you send a password?

Comment: Yes, so whenever the pod is starting up. It reads all the secrets it needs from the vault and it then sends the password.

Comment: Can you provide the channels stanza of the queue manager's qm.ini file?  Run `DIS QMGR CONNAUTH`, if there is a CONNAUTH value then run `DIS AUTHINFO(INSERT_CONNAUTH_VALUE)`.  Please edit and add the info to your question.

Comment: I have added the the output of both those commands. However, the qm.ini file does not have any channels section.

Comment: Try this `ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) ADOPTCTX(YES)` followed by `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)`.  I think this should solve your issue.

Comment: The issue was with the latest tag of our docker image. We then tried putting the latest image that was present in artifactory in the environment settings page and that solved the issue.